# GUI for XState JS to create finite state machine

Tags: open-source, javascript, gui, graphic-design

Is there a GUI for [XState Project](https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate) to simplify creating finite state machine?

Simple GUI for showcase exist as a demo: https://xstate.js.org/viz/

Can be any finite state machine OSS in JavaScript.

If no one do it, then I will propably try to create generator as a side project to simplify casting graphic design to user paths. It show all errors and needed screens for applications to work as good as lights on the road :)

Comment: I'm currently working on this! The first step is releasing a new visualizer/inspector, which will be done very soon.

Comment: Great to hear that @DavidKhourshid ! I think GUI will help other, non programmer in getting hook on this library. It will be essentially go-to solution, one on the world.